# Why is python3 calling python2 libraries?

Tags: python, django

The following error is generated from apache2 when trying to access a website created using django. as you can see from the error below, psycopg2 has failed to load. This is probably caused by the fact that it is trying to use python2 libraries instead of python3. So I am wondering how did this happen and what is the fix for it. Thanks

```
mod_wsgi (pid=2603): Target WSGI script '/var/www/iMARS/iMARS/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: 
mod_wsgi (pid=2603): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/iMARS/iMARS/wsgi.py'., referer: 
 Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: 
   File "/var/www/iMARS/iMARS/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>, referer: 
     application = get_wsgi_application(), referer: http://mana.smcnus.org/
   File "/opt/virtualenvs/iMARS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application, referer: 
     django.setup(), referer: 
   File "/opt/virtualenvs/iMARS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup, referer: 
     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS), referer: 
   File "/opt/virtualenvs/iMARS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate, referer: 
     app_config.import_models(all_models), referer: 
   File "/opt/virtualenvs/iMARS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models, referer: 
     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name), referer: 
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module, referer: 
     __import__(name), referer: 
   File "/var/www/iMARS/core/models.py", line 2, in <module>, referer: 
     from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, referer: 
   File "/opt/virtualenvs/iMARS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>, referer: 
     from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, referer: 
   File "/opt/virtualenvs/iMARS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contr ib/auth/base_user.py", line 49, in <module>, referer: 
     class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):, referer: 
   File "/opt/virtualenvs/iMARS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__, referer: 
     new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label)), referer: 
   File "/opt/virtualenvs/iMARS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 299, in add_to_class, referer: 
     value.contribute_to_class(cls, name), referer: 
   File "/opt/virtualenvs/iMARS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 263, in contribute_to_class, referer: 
     self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()), referer: 
   File "/opt/virtualenvs/iMARS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__, referer: 
     return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item), referer: 
   File "/opt/virtualenvs/iMARS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__, referer: 
     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE']), referer: 
   File "/opt/virtualenvs/iMARS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 116, in load_backend, referer: 
     return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name), referer: 
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module, referer: 
     __import__(name), referer: 
   File "/opt/virtualenvs/iMARS/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 24, in <module>, referer: 
     raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e), referer: 
 ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named _psycopg
```

Comment: How did you install the packages?

Comment: Padraic Cunningham, python3 is compiled from source. 
all the pip3 packages are installed into a virtualenv. The funny thing is that I am able to import the library using the python3 shell.

Comment: what makes you think you are using python 2 libraries? The stack shows `lib/python3.4/site-packages`. Are you sure you have installed pyscopg2 into the environment?

Comment: What does `from django.apps import AppConfig; print(AppConfig.path)` output? It seems like the switch from `py3` to `py2` is made in the `apps/config.py` file.

Comment: Try `pip -V` from the command line to check that you are using the correct environment and python version. Then try `python` and `import psycopg2` to confirm that the postgres bindings are installed. If that doesnt work you must do `pip install psycopg2`

Comment: Do you have  the correct wsgi version installed? I think you might have a mismatch https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/F_eQkxKEcGM

Comment: Haken Lid, if you look between the traces, u will notice that there is /usr/lib64/python2.7, which should not have happened.

Comment: @Jim, there is no path attribute/method from AppConfig

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham, you are right, the mod_wsgi is pointing to the wrong python path.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar issue with mysqlclient on CentOS 7 and apache where the default mod_wsgi is for python 2.

First try to check if you can run your Django application from the shell:

```
source /opt/virtualenvs/iMARS/bin/activate
python manage.py shell
```

If this works, the problem is with mod_wsgi which (on CentOS) you can update like this:

```
sudo yum erase mod_wsgi
sudo yum install python34u-mod_wsgi
sudo apachectl restart
```

This question provides the solution for Ubuntu: [Django MySQLdb issue on apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502772/django-mysqldb-issue-on-apache2)