# Django MySQLdb issue on apache2

Tags: django, ubuntu, apache2, mysql-python

i've installed on an ubuntu server django 1.9.4 and mysqlclient, i'm not under virtualenv.

If i run manage.py shell or runserver all goes right, but if i try through apache2 and wgi i got this error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: this is MySQLdb version (1, 3, 7, 'final', 1), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)
```

Python version 3.4

This is the apache2 vhost config:

```
WSGIPythonPath /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/:/home/ubuntu/www/mysite
```

DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/www/mysite
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

<Directory /home/ubuntu/www/mysite/mysite>
   <Files wsgi.py>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
       Require all granted
   </Files>
</Directory>
```

**SOLUTION:**

was a packages version error, with the following commands i solved it:

sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-python libapache2-mod-wsgi
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from the error message that your mysql version on system differs from MySQL-python-1.3.7.

Try uninstall MySQL-python and install 1.2.3 version.

Comment: i tried it but i can't find how to install this specific version of MySQL-python. And then, is strange that with django shell all works fine.