# Mysql connecting issue in django 1.9

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am getting the following error when trying to connect mysql db

```
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.154874 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314] mod_wsgi (pid=16451): Target WSGI script '/home/abhadran/network_python3/netmap/netmap/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.154920 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314] mod_wsgi (pid=16451): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/abhadran/network_python3/netmap/netmap/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.154942 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.154960 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]   File "/home/abhadran/network_python3/netmap/netmap/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.156034 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.156062 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]   File "/home/webdev01/pythonev3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.156125 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]     django.setup()
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.156140 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]   File "/home/webdev01/pythonev3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.156170 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.156182 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]   File "/home/webdev01/pythonev3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.156290 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]     app_config.import_models(all_models)
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.156310 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]   File "/home/webdev01/pythonev3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.156373 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.156392 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.156462 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]     __import__(name)
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.156478 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]   File "/home/webdev01/pythonev3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.156614 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]     from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.156636 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]   File "/home/webdev01/pythonev3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.156715 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]     class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.156732 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]   File "/home/webdev01/pythonev3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.157044 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]     new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.157061 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]   File "/home/webdev01/pythonev3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 307, in add_to_class
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.157078 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]     value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.157098 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]   File "/home/webdev01/pythonev3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 263, in contribute_to_class
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.157316 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]     self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.157335 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]   File "/home/webdev01/pythonev3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.157383 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]     return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.157398 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]   File "/home/webdev01/pythonev3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.157479 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.157492 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]   File "/home/webdev01/pythonev3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 116, in load_backend
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.157505 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]     return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.157513 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.157523 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]     __import__(name)
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.157529 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]   File "/home/webdev01/pythonev3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 28, in <module>
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.157625 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314]     raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
[Fri Mar 31 09:04:54.157650 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 16451] [remote 173.1.101.95:62314] ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: this is MySQLdb version (1, 3, 10, 'final', 0), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)
```

I am using django 1.9 version with python3.5.3. I have python installtion manually . Is this problem because of that??. Even after unistalling mysql client I am getting the above error.

pip freeze

```
configparser2==4.0.0
Django==1.9.12
django-tastypie==0.13.3
mod-wsgi==4.5.15
python-dateutil==2.6.0
python-mimeparse==1.6.0
requests==2.13.0
six==1.10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import PyMySQL
```

PyMySQL is the interface for python to connect to mysql.
can be downloaded using

```
pip install PyMySQL
```

Also mysqlclient can be used.

```
pip install mysqlclient.
```

Comment: this doesnt support python 3.x

Comment: Have you installed mysqlclient connector?pip install mysqlclient

Comment: Also remove MySQLdb.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139557/discussion-between-anish-and-shadow0359).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this instead?

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

That's how I get MySQL to work with Django (using 1.8.8 version though).

Answer (score 0):

Install PyMySQL and then in settings .py, type the following just below import os.

```
try:
    import pymysql
    pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with a python 3 virtualenv on apache on CentOS. This comes with python 2.7 as a default, which means apache uses mod_wsgi - the python 2.7 version of the module.
As you can see in the log, at some point it breaks out of your virtualenv and tries to use /usr/lib64/python2.7

What fixed it for me was to uninstall mod_wsgi and install the python 3 version. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44293768/7933618